# match tf state with the existing EC2 instance resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a tf state file stored in S3 bucket and it has this part about an EC2 instance:

```
       "attributes": {
                    "ami": "ami-0ed60c7b71b6610a6",
                    "arn": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:44444444444444:instance/i-07cff2b254b1cde3c",
                    "associate_public_ip_address": "false",
                    "availability_zone": "eu-west-1a",
                    "cpu_core_count": "1",
                    "cpu_threads_per_core": "2",
                    "credit_specification.#": "1",
                    "credit_specification.0.cpu_credits": "standard",
                    "disable_api_termination": "true",
                    "ebs_block_device.#": "2",
                    "ebs_block_device.2279853085.delete_on_termination": "true",
                    "ebs_block_device.2279853085.device_name": "",
                    "ebs_block_device.2279853085.encrypted": "false",
                    "ebs_block_device.2279853085.iops": "100",
                    "ebs_block_device.2279853085.kms_key_id": "",
                    "ebs_block_device.2279853085.snapshot_id": "snap-016c60740e5e35f25",
                    "ebs_block_device.2279853085.volume_id": "vol-03efc2ed4652597a9",
                    "ebs_block_device.2279853085.volume_size": "30",
                    "ebs_block_device.2279853085.volume_type": "gp2",
                    "ebs_block_device.897462451.delete_on_termination": "true",
                    "ebs_block_device.897462451.device_name": "/dev/xvde",
                    "ebs_block_device.897462451.encrypted": "false",
                    "ebs_block_device.897462451.iops": "100",
                    "ebs_block_device.897462451.kms_key_id": "",
                    "ebs_block_device.897462451.snapshot_id": "snap-0d3e70949c825b0e9",
                    "ebs_block_device.897462451.volume_id": "vol-0120f6b2038ec6066",
                    "ebs_block_device.897462451.volume_size": "30",
                    "ebs_block_device.897462451.volume_type": "gp2",
                    "ebs_optimized": "false",
                    "ephemeral_block_device.#": "0",
                    "get_password_data": "false",
                    "iam_instance_profile": "kp-prd-ec2",
                    "id": "i-07cff2b254b1cde3c",
                    "instance_state": "running",
                    "instance_type": "t3.micro",
                    "ipv6_address_count": "0",
                    "ipv6_addresses.#": "0",
                    "key_name": "gdp_-data-admin",
                    "monitoring": "false",
                    "network_interface.#": "0",
                    "password_data": "",
                    "placement_group": "",
                    "primary_network_interface_id": "eni-09e9454cb4954ecde",
                    "private_dns": "ip-10-194-27-15.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
                    "private_ip": "10.194.27.15",
                    "public_dns": "",
                    "public_ip": "",
                    "root_block_device.#": "1",
                    "root_block_device.0.delete_on_termination": "true",
                    "root_block_device.0.encrypted": "false",
                    "root_block_device.0.iops": "240",
                    "root_block_device.0.kms_key_id": "",
                    "root_block_device.0.volume_id": "vol-0d53a53b8825c9889",
                    "root_block_device.0.volume_size": "80",
                    "root_block_device.0.volume_type": "gp2",
                    "security_groups.#": "0",
                    "source_dest_check": "true",
                    "subnet_id": "subnet-53af101a",
                    "tenancy": "default",
                    "user_data": "9306f6c8f4c0679a11f00c8e5dbaf14ef5944e65",

                    "vpc_security_group_ids.#": "3",
                    "vpc_security_group_ids.1370631249": "sg-fb68699f",
                    "vpc_security_group_ids.359020622": "sg-22b0be44",
                    "vpc_security_group_ids.41262993": "sg-3d52f758"
```

and when I run my terraform, I get that it wants to force some changes, hence, it will have to destroy and create again the EC2 instance:

```
   disable_api_termination:                                             "true" => "true"
      ebs_block_device.#:                                                  "2" => "2"
      ebs_block_device.2279853085.delete_on_termination:                   "true" => "false" (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.2279853085.device_name:                             "/dev/xvdd" => "" (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.3965576335.delete_on_termination:                   "" => "true" (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.3965576335.device_name:                             "" => "/dev/xvdd" (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.3965576335.encrypted:                               "" => <computed> (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.3965576335.iops:                                    "" => ""
      ebs_block_device.3965576335.kms_key_id:                              "" => <computed> (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.3965576335.snapshot_id:                             "" => <computed> (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.3965576335.volume_id:                               "" => <computed>
      ebs_block_device.3965576335.volume_size:                             "" => "10" (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.3965576335.volume_type:                             "" => "gp2" (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.3986656952.delete_on_termination:                   "" => "true" (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.3986656952.device_name:                             "" => "/dev/xvde" (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.3986656952.encrypted:                               "" => <computed> (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.3986656952.iops:                                    "" => ""
      ebs_block_device.3986656952.kms_key_id:                              "" => <computed> (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.3986656952.snapshot_id:                             "" => <computed> (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.3986656952.volume_id:                               "" => <computed>
      ebs_block_device.3986656952.volume_size:                             "" => "10" (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.3986656952.volume_type:                             "" => "gp2" (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.897462451.delete_on_termination:                    "true" => "false" (forces new resource)
      ebs_block_device.897462451.device_name:                              "/dev/xvde" => "" (forces new resource)
      ebs_optimized:                                                       "true" => "false" (forces new resource)
```

I absolutely do not want to recreate the instance because it is used by another team, so I want to match the tf state to what I have in the console. Any help with this please ?
How can I do this without losing any data?

Comment: What does the Terraform code that defines the resource look like? It looks like Terraform is saying that you haven't defined the EBS volumes that are attached to it according to the state so Terraform wants to remove those EBS volumes. But because that's not doable when the EBS volumes are directly attached to the instance rather than via separate `aws_ebs_volume` and `aws_ebs_volume_attachment` resources so it has to delete the whole instance and rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute a `terraform state rm` to remove the resource from the current state. This would then cause Terraform to attempt to create a new resource. Therefore, you would then need to execute a `terraform import` to import the resource state into your state file, and have it targeted by the resource you want to match it against. Since you do not share the full resource information, nor the information for the AWS instance you do not want to alter, I will list these commands as if the resource is called `foo` and is not encapsulated within a module, and as if the instance is named `id-123456789`. Please share more information if this cannot be translated into your situation:

```
terraform state rm aws_instance.foo
terraform import aws_instance.foo id-123456789
```

[terraform import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/usage.html)
[terraform state rm](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/rm.html)